# ffmpeg - How to configure ref param for h264_nvenc encoder

Tags: ffmpeg, nvidia, encoder, libx264, nvenc

I'm trying to configure and replace libx264 encoder with h264_nvenc NVIDIA encoder.
I want to replace the parameter `-x264-params ref=4` with it's parallel nvenc parameter.
I used `ffmpeg -hide_banner -h encoder=h264_nvenc` to see all available options but couldn't find any proper replacement.
Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like in the latest ffmpeg source they added `dpb_size` parameter and it somewhat directly infulences `refs` parameter internally. Give it a shot.

Comment: Worked! Thanks! Also had to add `-coder` with `cabac` for it to work but problem solved!